# Material design list element to card transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I read [elevation](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html) section in the material design docs and there are various issues for the implementation.

I try understand, how this [elevation](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/fff057c227cb393074c97bd3b92e3e63060a0f6c184e384da82b9855f766af6aca9ae9caef1b7fdfb5620e39c4138ecc7ed75e8fb82b16471bc52e26384719ef) can be implemented (html+css+js).. I have little experience with html+css , so I will be glad of any hint that will clarify the issues.

It is especially unclear how the list item is excluded from the list and expanded to the full screen while the other elements remain in place.

It is also unclear how the animation is implemented first elevating then expanding.

Comment: is the box shadow worked for you ?

Comment: I think this is implemented like a hero widget in flutter. Two different divs (list element and card) on separated layers (in diffent block elements) with fixed positions. Expanding card is scale or translate transformation. And a hero part used for an element expanding flow animation.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be useful for someone

1. [Container transform spec](https://material.io/design/motion/the-motion-system.html#container-transform)
2. [Material elevation](https://material.io/develop/web/components/elevation)
3. [Performant Expandable Animations](https://css-tricks.com/performant-expandable-animations-building-keyframes-on-the-fly/)
4. [requestAnimationFrame boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/bendc/4d66878dce526da728997d1e4e39325f) with [tutorial](https://medium.com/@bdc/gain-motion-superpowers-with-requestanimationframe-ecc6d5b0d9a4)
5. [Google Material Design Easings](https://gist.github.com/lucasdidthis/7380cc63968554fd79a010a789d69f09) and [spec](https://material.io/design/motion/speed.html#easing)
6. [bezier-easing](https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing) by JavaSctipt